# SQL Cluster Between Cloud Providers - Multi Cloud SQL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sql-server, azure

I want to explore the options available to me in setting up MS SQL replication between Azure and Amazon AWS.

Has anyone got any ideas?  I think Always On Availability Groups is off the table.

**-- Edit**

Ok so a couple of suggestions asked me to put some constraints/requirements into play - here they are:

1. The product has to be Microsoft SQL server.  I do not care whether
   it is installed on a VM or part of the managed offerings of each
   provider (RDS/Elastic etc etc) it just has to act like a SQL server.
2. Master / Slave setup.  Do not worry about routing or anything like that, simply the server in one of the clouds will be the master, the server in the other the slave.
3. Data sync - There will be something in place to sync the data between master and slave.  Imagine log shipping from cloud to cloud.

Comment: This is a question with some interesting potential, but it's a little vague.  You might have better luck with a more specific question.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a deal life example or even a fictional example to enable users to better answer the question. E.g I have a server with ms sql installed and in trying to achieve replication to a backup server

Comment: Have you instead looked at Azure site recovery?

Comment: Did you try searching for this? I found two articles that had some useful information in 10 seconds. I don't see a problem if you're using SQL Server on EC2 instances, but if you mean between managed database servers that's different. Suggest you edit your question to make it more precise.

Comment: Is it running is Azure SQL Database or a VM? How big is the database? What's your recovery point objective (how many hours of data entry you can lose during a disaster recovery)? What's your recovery time objective (how many hours max before your DR site is online)?

Comment: @KatherineVillyard updated.

Comment: @Tim I have read that due to the networking stack of EC2, MSSQL AOAG does not work.

Comment: @GregGalloway I dont think there is point thinking about that level of requirements until we figure out if it is possible.

Comment: @divinci figure out if what is possible? See? Define the requirements first. I can think of half a dozen solutions.

Comment: Something I've noticed over the years - questions such as these (novel and untypical) are better received if more context is provided as to why it needs to be in this specific configuration. I suspect there are many reasons why a solution needs to span cloud providers, as opposed to just designing a solution that uses two providers for no specific reason.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is actually a line in your question - log shipping from cloud to cloud. There are 4 basic components:

- On your primary SQL Server, write your transaction log backups to a file share
- Sync that file share to a cloud-based file service
- On your secondary SQL Server, sync that file share locally as well
- On your secondary SQL Server, restore the backups that show up in that file share

The specifics on how you implement it vary based on what file sync app you want to use, which clouds you're using, etc. Google commissioned us to write a white paper on how to do it with Google Compute Engine, and you can [download that from our site](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/new-white-paper-build-sql-server-disaster-recovery-plan-google-compute-engine/), or [from Google](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/sql-server-disaster-recovery-plan-compute-engine). That white paper is very specific to Google, but you can use those same techniques to do it with Amazon or Microsoft Azure.

Failover isn't automatic - but you wouldn't want it to be, not when either cloud provider can temporarily lose connectivity to another. You want to build in as much resiliency as possible for a scenario like this, which means you wouldn't want the SQL Servers talking directly to each other.